# Gram-Schimdt get the Legendre polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, orthogonality

When I apply the Gram-Schmidt algorithm I don't understand why I don't get the Legendre polynomials. When I apply this algorithm I always get monic polynomials whereas the Legendre polynomials aren't all monics.

So we want to get an orthogonal basis for the inner product : $\langle f,g\rangle:=\int fg$. To so we are going to apply G-S algorithm on the basis: $(1,X,X^2,...)$

We have : $P_0 = 1$, $P_1 = X$ and

$$P_2 = X^2 - \frac{\langle X^2, 1\rangle}{\|1 \|}1 - \frac{\langle X^2, X\rangle}{\|X \|^2}X$$

Hence $P_2$ is a monic polynomial here while the second Legendre polynomial isn't monic.

And more generally we have :

$$P_n = X^n - \sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} \frac{\langle X^n, P_i\rangle }{\| P_i \|^2} P_i$$
So all the polynomials I get thanks to G-S are monic.

So where am I going wrong here?

Thank you !

Comment: After G-S, you should **normalize** these $P$.

Comment: @xbh Thank you for your answe, but what do you mean by normalize ? What calculation I need to do in order to normalize theses polynmials ?. Thank you !

Comment: A vector with length/module $1$ is called a normalized vector. So for $\boldsymbol x$, its normalization is $\boldsymbol x / \Vert \boldsymbol x \Vert$.

Comment: Note that Legendre polynomials are generally normalised such that $P_n(1) = 1$. However, I don't know why such an unusual normalisation is chosen

Comment: @Damien $X^2-1/3$ is a monic polynomial.

Comment: @xbh I see ty. The calculations are becoming a bit heavy if we want the normalize polynomials...

Comment: Sorry, I made a confusion in the English terms. Effectively, you will get monic polynomials *before* normalisation

Comment: @Damien np, do you actually know why it's better to work with normalize polynomials  ?

Comment: Normalising is not strictly mandatory. If you normalise in the classic way (module 1), you simplify the general G-S formula, but with more complex polynomials. The classic way is to normalise with $P_n(1) = 1$, and you will get the usual Legendre polynomials. I don't know why such a normalisation is used. Maybe to impose that all polynomials have their values in $[-1, 1]$

Comment: @Damien Thank you for your answer. Actually I don't know either why such a normalization is used... Also the inner product for Legendre polynomials is using the mass function $w = 1$ whereas for Tchebychev polynomials the function $w(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$ is used. While $w = 1$ seems kind of "natural" I don't get why the function $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$ is used. Do you have any ideas ? Thank you.

Comment: I guess you know what are the Chebyshev polynomials: $P_n(\cos\theta) = \cos{n\theta}$. This mass function is such that these polynomials are orthogonal when integrated between $-1$ and $1$. This corresponds to the orthogonality of $\cos(nx)$ functions when integrated between $0$ and $\pi$, with a mass function equal to $1$ in this case

Comment: @Damien Great ty for your answer !